# C++17 file path decomposition into folder names

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

I was going through the specification of c++17 [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) trying to find the function to get the vector from the decomposition of all the folder names in the given path, but couldn't find any. What is the reason? Seems like a basic functionality to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that does not need to be in filesystem. filesystem::path just exposes iterators, and vector's constructor does the rest:

```
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

using path = std::experimental::filesystem::path;
path p("C:/RootDir/SubDirectory/SubSubDirectory/SomeFile.txt");

int main() {
    std::vector<path::iterator::value_type> v(p.begin(), p.end());

    for( auto itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution! Is it also possible to get the path objects instead of path iterators in the vector in the similar way? I know, that the difference is minimal, but still?

Comment: So, the path to C:/, followed by the path to C:/RootDir, etc. until finally p itself is returned?